# Partial Function values for sorting

Tags: scala

I want to sort a list dependent on an external predicate.  I'm looking for alternatives in Scala that are expressive.  I'm not crazy about the two alternatives I've come up with.  Given:

```
val lst = List(5,4,3,2,1)
val needsSorting = false
```

I want to be able to write a concise sort expression like so:

```
lst.sortBy(sortDecision)
```

to give me the list sorted either in ascending order:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5) // if needSorting == true
```

or in the original chronological order

```
List(5,4,3,2,1) // if needSorting == false
```

BUT I want the decision on HOW to sort to be embedded in my `sortDecision` partial function.  What I've come up with are two alternatives:

Alternative 1:

```
val sortDecision: PartialFunction[Int,Int] = {
    case x: Int if (needsSorting) =>  x 
    case _ => -1
}
```

Alternative 2:

```
val sortDecision: PartialFunction[Int,Int] = {
    case x: Int =>  if (needsSorting) x else -1
}
```

but in both cases I have the !needsSorting case having to produce some filler (in this case -1) for the compiler to be happy.  This is bad code smell.  Can anyone offer an alternative to accomplish the same thing that is a bit more elegant?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the "code smell" is here. But if you don't like see `-1` there, you can use a constant `val NoSort = -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the more elegant way is to not sort at all if `needsSorting == false` because I think it is the only way that your intent will be completely clear.

Another way to achieve this would be to supply an `Ordering` but you'd end up having to do something similar there (such as comparing dummy values) if you want to make the decision within the `Ordering`.

You might already know that the reason that returning `-1` leaves the list unsorted is that sortBy transforms each `Int` into another value and then uses that value when comparing. So in your example it's like sorting `List(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)` and then putting back the original values. Because scala sort is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts) this leaves all the elements in the same order.

Comment: So will the sort always happen?  I was hoping I could short-circuit the sort inside the partial function.  If I can't, then yes, I need to test the predicate BEFORE even doing the sort.  I think I'll go for intent.  Thanks.